# Advanced search in sidebar categories

Tags: magento2

Is there a way to put advanced search form in category sidebar in Magento 2.2.6? The form is in catalogsearch/advanced/ page

Answer (score 0):

Go to `catalog_category_view_type_default.xml` file and add below code:

```
<referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
      <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="advanced/form.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Override Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form

Create a custom module and in etc/di.xml add

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" type="Ea\SidebarSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" />
</config>
```

> Create File Ea\SidebarSearch\Block\Advanced\Form.php

```
<?php
    namespace Ea\SidebarSearch\Block\Advanced;

    class Form extends \Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form
    {
            /**
             * Retrieve search form action url
             *
             * @return string
             */
            public function getSearchPostUrl()
            {
                return $this->getUrl('catalogsearch/advanced/result');
            }

    }
?>
```

> Add view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="sidebar.main">
            <block class="Magento\CatalogSearch\Block\Advanced\Form" name="catalogsearch_advanced_form" template="advanced/form.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Add file view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml and copy content from vendor/magento/module-catalog-search/view/frontend/templates/advanced/form.phtml